# Rails Inner Join not working but the SQL looks right

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inner-join

So I have 2 tables that are joined by an ID. I'm in rails console and I type:

```
Programmer.all(:joins=>:assignment)
```

the sql that is generated is:

```
SELECT `programmers`.* FROM `programmers` INNER JOIN `assignments` ON `assignments`.`programmer_id` = `programmers`.`id`
```

The output that is generated is the same as Programmer.all. Why doesn't it include the assignments data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I majorly overanalyzed your question. If you just want to join any available assignments to programmers, you're looking for:

```
Programmer.all(:include => :assignment)
```

Rails is designed so that `:joins` is used to perform things like sorting and grabbing certain records but still keep the query result to a minimum size -- meaning, `:joins` never actually includes the results from the joined table in the result.

Now here's my previous answer that assumes you want to perform an `INNER JOIN` to get only the programmers with assignments, but you also want that data. In that case, you have two options:

**#1 - Use `:select`**

```
Programmer.all(:select => '*', :joins => :assignment)
```

That will change the SQL to:

```
SELECT * FROM `programmers` INNER JOIN `assignments` ON `assignments`.`programmer_id` = `programmers`.`id`
```

Upside: You get the query you want and all the data is somewhere, at least.

Downside: `assignments` is assigned directly to the `Programmer` object and not to the proper place at `Programmer.assignment`.

**#2 - Use a combination of `:joins` and `:includes`**

```
Programmer.all(:joins => :assignment, :include => :assignment)
```

Which produces the SQL:

```
SELECT `programmers`.* FROM `programmers` INNER JOIN `assignments` ON `assignments`.`id` = `programmers`.`assignment_id`
SELECT `assignments`.* FROM `assignments` WHERE (`assignments`.`id` IN  (?) )
```

Upside: All your data is in the right place now. You can refer to `programmer.assignment` without another query.

Downside: You are running that extra query in a lot of instances. I am fairly sure that Rails tries to optimize this when it needs to, though, and if not, it shouldn't cause you too much overhead.

Comment: this changed the sql to what you have listed, but the output is still purely from the Programmer table.

Comment: well, technically it adds all of that information to the Programmer object... so say you have `assignment.title`, it would be accessible at `programmer.title`.. not ideal.

Comment: i've updated the answer to give you a couple options. neither is as straightforward as a single query that puts everything in place, but it is essentially what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do like

```
Programmer.includes(:assignment)
```